# Twitter login in cordova android app

Tags: javascript, cordova, twitter, ionic-framework

I want to use twitter login in my app built using Cordova this app is for android. Any integrate twitter native login JavaScript. I searched on google but didn't find any solution for that.

Answer (score 3):

use ngCordova module it has all things all native plugins available for cordova and phonegap
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/

Comment: The Oauth module of ngCordova is light weight and should be very simple to add to your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but you need to be using API v1.1. 
Here is a tutorial:

http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms

Moreover, you may also use Auth0's platform to achieve this:
https://auth0.com/authenticate/phonegap/twitter